# node.js - how do I run a series of callback functions in order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, synchronous

like many other peoples, I want to turn a async function of a third party module (Patio) into a sync function.

```
function get_user_message_list(parameters, array, response)
{
var new_array = [];
for (var i in array) {

    var json = array[i];
    json['content']['users_seen'] = ["1757842565"];
    json['content']['users_not_seen'] = [];

    new_array.push(json);
}

console.log("NEW ARRAY :");
console.log(new_array);

response.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type':'application/json'});
response.end(JSON.stringify(new_array));
}

function get_json_message(parameters, json)
{
console.log("JSON OBJECT :");
console.log(json);
var dataset = db.from(TABLES.USER).join(TABLES.MOVIE_LIST, {MLUserId: sql.URId}).join(TABLES.MOVIE, {MVId: sql.MLMovieId});

dataset.where('MLSeen={seen} AND MVSourceId={movie} AND MVSource={source} AND URId!={user}', {seen: 1, movie: json['content']['movie_id'], source: json['content']['movie_source'], user:parameters.FACEBOOK_ID}).all().then(function(users){
    if (users) {
        for (var j in users) {
            json['content']['users_seen'].push(users[j].URId);
        }
    }

    //console.log(json['content']['users_seen']);

    dataset.where('MLSeen={seen} AND MVSourceId={movie} AND MVSource={source} AND URId!={user}', {seen: 0, movie: json['content']['movie_id'], source: json['content']['movie_source'], user:parameters.FACEBOOK_ID}).all().then(function(users){
        if (users) {
            for (var j in users) {
                json['content']['users_not_seen'].push(users[j].URId);
            }
        }

        console.log(json);
    }, errorHandler);
}, errorHandler);
}
```

In the get_user_message_list function I iterate into an array and for each iteration I calling the async function. In this async function I'm using Patio module to make request to MySQL database. But like you can see, I must wait for the query result to be get after sending a result to the previous function.

How can I wait for the query result to be got before I send it to the next function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You CAN and you SHOULD turn async functions into something that behaves like sync functions when a problem needs to be fixed. You can't is never the correct answer, the shouldn't is for the programmer to answer.

So, I recently found some code in the nodeunit module which may help you. It fires the async functions, keep track of which are ready. After all requests are in, fires the callback. This could be the idea behind the solution to your problem (so no, this is not the final solution).

```
async.forEachSeries = function (arr, iterator, callback) {
    if (!arr.length) {
        return callback();
    }
    var completed = 0;
    var iterate = function () {
        iterator(arr[completed], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                callback = function () {};
            }
            else {
                completed += 1;
                if (completed === arr.length) {
                    callback();
                }
                else {
                    iterate();
                }
            }
        });
    };
    iterate();
};
```

This test triggered me to see how it was done:

```
exports['series'] = function (test) {
    var call_order = [];
    async.series([
        function (callback) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                call_order.push(1);
                callback(null, 1);
            }, 25);
        },
        function (callback) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                call_order.push(2);
                callback(null, 2);
            }, 50);
        },
        function (callback) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                call_order.push(3);
                callback(null, 3, 3);
            }, 15);
        }
    ],
    function (err, results) {
        test.equals(err, null);
        test.same(results, [1, 2, [3, 3]]);
        test.same(call_order, [1, 2, 3]);
        test.done();
    });
};
```

Happy programming!

Comment: This is a very short-sighted answer.. This solution to the problem can cause more issues than it solves

Answer (score 0):

You can't and you shouldn't. This would effectively block your Node.JS server and you would loose every advantage Node.JS provides. Also it is against the whole asynchronous idea behind Node.JS.

Just pass `callback` parameter to your function:

```
function get_json_message(parameters, json, callback){ // <---- note the callback
    // some other stuff
    dataset.where( ...
        // some other stuff
        dataset.where( ...
            // some other stuff
            // I've finished the job, call the callback
            callback(); // <--- you can pass additional params here
        });
    });
}
```

and call it like this:

```
get_json_message( params, json, function() {
    console.log('Hello world!');
    // do whatever you like inside callback
});
```

Comment: You assume that you're running a node.js server and not a script... Don't assume.

Comment: not a big fan of blanket answers or saying a language or framework dictates how things should be done. Anyone who has spent a bit of time developing real world applications would have come across this problem, usually because of libraries that don't use callbacks, for example dynamicHelpers in express.

Comment: This snippet from the docs of the deasync module describe a good situation when you "should".

Suppose you maintain a library that exposes getData.
Under the hood data is saved in a file so you implemented getData using Node.js built-in fs.readFileSync. It's obvious both getData and fs.readFileSync are sync functions. One day you were told to switch the underlying data source to MongoDB which can only be accessed async. You were told to avoid pissing off your users, getData API cannot be changed to return a promise or demand a callback parameter. How do you meet both requirements?

Comment: @EricIhli the solution is to never use sync IO. Imo it's a mistake that such thing even exists in node.js. Then you have no problem when switching. Deasync is not really js. It's a lib that hacks the internals of the V8 engine. Yes, everything is possible when you hack the source code. But node.js was never meant to be used like this. Also I would be very careful when using the lib. Even the author himself writes on GitHub: `though it's just a hack and I'd strongly recommend not to use it for anything.`

Comment: @freakish Even if one believes the solution is to never use sync IO, a lot of people work with and have to deal with code other people wrote. It's not always in the cards to perform a refactor. 

Besides that, what if the getData API wasn't IO? What if it was reading from memory but needed to be refactored to read from IO?

Comment: @EricIhli then I advice doing the refactoring. Mistakes happen. But they are also lessons. You should try to predict up front what the function is supposed to do and think about the design. Hacks is not the way to solve problems. Sometimes you have to refactor half of your code. Shit happens. But still, on the long run it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [syncrhonize.js](http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html) with great success. There's even a pending pull request (which works quite well) to support async functions which have multiple parameters. Far better and easier to use than node-sync imho. Added bonus that it has easy-to-understand and thorough documentation, whereas node-sync does not.